# How to concatenate strings in python

Tags: string, concatenation

I'm trying to run a command in Python by concatenating two strings, each string has an absolute path in it. It's throwing an error. Below is the code and error for reference. Kindly correct me where am I going wrong.

Code:

```
def test_execute_resources_temp_dir(self):
sourcePath = Path("Gemini_logo.png").absolute()
print(sourcePath)
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
    destination = Path(tmpdirname).resolve("Gemini_logo_converted.jpg")
    print('created temporary directory', destination)
command = "magick convert" + sourcePath +" "+ destination
formatConversion = FormatConversion()
formatConversion.executeCommand(command)
```

Error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "WindowsPath") to str test_FormatConversion.py:65: TypeError

Comment: Have you searched the web about this?

Comment: Yes, I have done. What I understood out of my research is - it is taking "magick convert" as a String and  (sourcePath +" "+ destination)  are windows path. It suggested to use single quotes and double quotes(giving whole command as a single string). Tried using it, still I'm getting an error (No such file exists)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `sourcePath` with `str(sourcePath)`.

Similarly, you can replace `destination` with `str(destination)`

```
command = "magick convert" + str(sourcePath) +" "+ str(destination)
```

Comment: Thank you Wyck, I have tried the below code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me

```
def test_execute_resources_temp_dir(self):
        os.chdir('..')
        sourcePath = Path("src\\resources\\Gemini_logo.png").absolute()
        print(sourcePath)
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
            # os.mkdir(os.path.basename(tmpdirname))
            destination = Path(tmpdirname+"/Gemini_logo_converted1.jpg")
            print('created temporary directory', destination)
            command = **"magick convert"+" "+ str(sourcePath) + " " + str(destination)**
```